# bash find list of archived files with wildcard in while loop

Tags: bash, find, bash-scripting, wildcards

I have a few thousand gzipped text files in different subdirectories and used a subset of these files as input for a project a few years ago. Back then I had an unzipped copy of the files I actually used in one directory, but deleted this and kept only a list of these unzipped files in that folder

This was my initial idea, `LIST` is the list of files. `PARENTDIR` is the toplevel directory in which all files reside in various sub directories. The idea was to find all the archives in whatever sub directory they are and gunzip them to `NEWDIR`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash    

LIST="listfile.txt"
PARENTDIR="/home/user/old/project"
NEWDIR="/home/user/old/project/2016"

while read line;
do
    ARCHIVE="$(find $PARENTDIR -name "$line*")"
    gunzip --stdout $ARCHIVE >$NEWDIR/$line
done <$LIST
```

I don't seem to get the find command right. It works without the variables, but not with, even without the command substitution, calling on the command line. My combination of quotes and wild cards is not quite correct, but I can't get it right, variable expansion doesn't help either and I guess I'm stuck...

Comment: Add `echo "$ARCHIVE"` to see what it happened... or `set +` before and `set - ` after the part to debug. If there are spaces you want to use `" $variable"`... what happens if find found more than one archive compliant with the key? Better `find... -exec gzip {} ;`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, `echo "$ARCHIVE"` outputs an empty line, `echo $line` shows what I expect. I included `set +` and `set -` but nothing seemed to happen either - but I'm not exactly familiar with set

Comment: @Hastur, you're right, my tests show I have a few thousand duplicates, but not all. In principle, the first text file could be overwriten by the second, would  `find... -exec gzip {} ;` just decompress the archive twice as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought of using the `-exec` option for `find` but this would not work due to the redirection operator used with the `gunzip` command. One solution would be to perform the operation in two steps:

### 1. Copy the archives into `$NEWDIR`:

```
    while read line
    do
        find "$PARENTDIR" -name "$line*" -exec cp -v {} "$NEWDIR" \;
    done < "$LIST"
```

This should work with [POSIX-compatible](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) versions of `find` – not only GNU find.

#### Avoid over-writing of similarly named files

If you have duplicate filenames, they’ll be over-written in `$NEWDIR`. If you
want to avoid over-writing the files, you’d have to recreate the directory
tree inside `$NEWDIR`. This can be done using the `install` command from *GNU coreutils* which creates *all* parts of the path similar to `mkdir -p`.

```
    cd "$NEWDIR"
    while read line
    do
        find . -name "$line*" -exec install -D {} $NEWDIR/{} \;
    done < "$LIST"
    cd -
```

### 2. Decompress the copied files:

```
    find "$NEWDIR" -exec gunzip {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks, the actual solution to the initial problem was to change the directory, but I wouldn't have tried it without your suggestion. I executed the script from within `$NEWDIR` and thought this should do given the absolute paths. When moving it to `$PARENTDIR` find works, which I don't really understand. I used the `-exec cp` statement because of course I created duplicates back then

Comment: Thanks for the `install` command, I didn't know this one! In this case I can accept overwriting, it's not critical but I'll keep the `install` command in mind for future use.

Comment: @Carambakaracho  I tried to recreate your setup on my system and I didn't need to change directory to `$PARENTDIR`. Without debugging information, it's hard to say why you had to.  BTW, I've edited my answer to include a way to avoid over-writing similarly named files.